# How to serialize a typed integer using Golang's ASN.1 module?

Tags: go, serialization, asn.1

I want to define an ASN.1 structure with a numeric field. I use a custom type for that number, to make it clear what kind of value one deals with and let the compiler catch some type-related errors (e.g., attempts to use other numerical values that don't semantically fit into the field).

However, the serializer doesn't know how to deal with this field, because it is not a Go primitive type.

Here is a minimal example that illustrates the problem:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/asn1"
    "fmt"
)

type MessageType uint

const (
    Signal  MessageType = 1
    Payload             = 2
    Control             = 3
)

type Packet struct {
    Type MessageType
    // more stuff here ...
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Signal)

    var packet Packet
    packet.Type = Payload

    fmt.Println(asn1.Marshal(packet))

}
```

When I run it, the error is `[] asn1: structure error: unknown Go type: main.MessageType`. It works if I use a plain integer instead of the custom `MessageType`, but in this case I don't get the benefit of using specific types.

What is the proper way of handling this scenario in Go? The documentation of the ASN1 module doesn't provide any examples that address this question.

Answer (score 0):

golang encoding/asn1 is a low level library ... it is not an ASN.1 compiler

So it's normal you can only encode basic types

You will need to write more code before it calls encoding/asn1 library

You can do it manually if the problem you want to solve is very simple.

However, the normal process when you use ASN.1 is:

1. Write an ASN.1 specification
2. Use a tool to compile it and produce stubs in your preferred language
3. Write some code that will use these stubs

I think you won't find free tools to do that in Go

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "write more code before it calls..." part? Are there some standard "hooks" that can be optionally invoked to coerce my custom type into a number just before the serialization functions kick in? I am not a seasoned Go programmer, so I might be asking about something obvious.